# How to make a virtual layer from ogr geometry?

Tags: python, ogr, layers

I know how to do this:

```
nodes = driver.Open(node_nav,0)
node_lyr = nodes.GetLayer()  
node_lyr.SetSpatialFilter(None)
```

But how do can use the layer methods on a geometry I created from scratch?

```
multip=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiPoint)
for n in nodes:
    p=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    x,y = n.node
    x = float(x)/dim
    y = float(y)/dim

    p.AddPoint(x,y)
    multip.AddGeometry(p)
```

This is the traceback for this attempt:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 2927, in <lambda>
 __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, Geometry, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 55, in _swig_getattr
raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: SetSpatialFilter
```

I don't want to save the geometry in a shape file ([like it is described  here for example)](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/gdal-shapefile-points-save.html).

Comment: `AttributeError: SetSpatialFilter` This just means the attribute isn't found on the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write the geometry to an in-memory dataset using the '/vsimem/path_file.shp' [virtual file system](http://erouault.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/new-gdal-virtual-file-system-to-read.html).

e.g.

```
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName( 'ESRI Shapefile' )
ds = drv.CreateDataSource( "/vsimem/blahblah.shp" )
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Have you any experience using it? Can you provide some example code?

Comment: @LarsVegas - yes, I use /vsimem regularly with GDAL, seems to work just as well with OGR.  There's example code in [your link](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/gdal-shapefile-points-save.html) and the [OGR API tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html). The only difference is instead of calling `ds = drv.CreateDataSource( r"c:\somedir\blahblah.shp" )` you call `ds = drv.CreateDataSource( "/vsimem/blahblah.shp" )`

Comment: This works great! Very useful information you provided here. I created a point shape file with ~300.000 geometries and two attribute fields in less than a second. Impressive.