# Python: best practise to ceate a large shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, performance

What is the best approach to create a create a very large shapefile (close to the max of 2GB) using python? Best approach means: robust and fast. Above all fast.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: May be because of lack of information in your question? IMHO best practice in your case is NOT TO USE shp-files at all. Use spatial databases for such amount of data.

Comment: Out of what will you create this shapefile? Surely there are some inputs or specifications--otherwise, the fastest way is to use an operating system call to copy an existing 2 GB shapefile :-).

Comment: Haha! Good one. Well, this question was intended to be open. There is one specific use case right now (~700.000 point geomtries with two attribute columns (strings)) but I was interested in general thoughts about fast ways to create a shapefile from scratch.

Comment: @SS_Rebelious, in many cases I agree, since they have several limitations. However, in simpler circumstances shapefiles are still useful, e.g supported by numerous systems, quick & easy to handle etc.

Comment: For what it is worth, [here are some short examples](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles/52708#52708) to create Shapefiles with GDAL/OGR or Fiona.

Answer (score 15):

I want to take the chance of promoting OGR's virtual file system that writes geometries to a in-memory dataset.

Using it is simple as @Luke demonstrated in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67104/how-to-make-a-virtual-layer-from-ogr-geometry)

```
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName( 'ESRI Shapefile' )
ds = drv.CreateDataSource(r'/vsimem/virtual.shp')
```

This works just great. Creating a point shape file with ~300.000 geometries and two attribute fields takes less than two seconds. Impressive.

Comment: If your dealing with a really large shape file won't this get slow once it eats all your memory and swaps?

Answer (score 3):

A slow method is updating the shapefile, on disk, for each record. I would look for a Python library that allows you to create an in-memory layer, then write the shapefile to disk in a single function or transactions. Fione/shapely may offer something. Also, ogr2ogr will create a shapefile from csv, or another shapefile, etc. Ogr2ogr is written in C or C++ so it should be fast, but is not a pure Python solution. You'll want to define the shapefile attributes as tight as possible to keep the shapefile as small as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If Python is desired for this task, then the [GDAL/OGR Python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) is probably the best free option.

See [HERE](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html) for a python example showing how to create/write to a shapefile.